# How to POST binary data using cURL in PHP?

Tags: curl, http-post, binary-data, php-curl, azure-cognitive-services

Using the Microsoft Azure OCR I only get words in my response. This is a problem in my case since I will need to get numeric values (partially code). The Read API documentation is really poor and I could not figure out how to send my binary data file using cURL in PHP.

in OCR (https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f20d/console) this will be the request:

```
POST https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.1/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=true HTTP/1.1
Host: westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

[Binary image data]
```

in PHP my code looks like this:

```
$mime = mime_content_type($files['tmp_name']);
$postfields = array('image' => new CURLFile($files['tmp_name'], $mime, $files['name']));
            
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$ocr_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: multipart/form-data', 
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: '.$ocr_key
            ));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This works for OCR but when I want to use the Read  API multipart/form-data is not an option as content-type. Changing the content-type (and the URL of course) in the Read API does not help. I have already tried several ways.
Read API documentation: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005

Is there anyone who can help me out please ?

Comment: Hi, you should rephrase your question and add more details about what is your exact issue. Here you are mixing details about OCR vs Read and we don't clearly understand where you are blocked and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005) to PHP code for Read API, Supported body input methods: raw image binary or image URL.

```
<?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2('https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.1/read/analyze');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '{subscription key}',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
    'language' => '{string}',
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```